# Firebase can't find project ID Firebase Admin SDK cloud messaging

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to my Node.js server to be able to automatically send firebase cloud messages to devices with specific registration tokens. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) discuss several ways I can authorize my Node.js server, including relying on the default project authorization if I am deploying with Google Cloud (which I am). However, while I'm testing my Node.js server on my local machine, it seems like I need to set an environment variable with the path of a downloaded configuration `.json`.

I did this with:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/johnsorensen/Documents/Ops Docs/notificationsmrp-firebase-adminsdk-h86ml-cd2d8d8f7a.json"`

I can verify that this indeed the correct file path, as I had Mac's finder return it to me.

When I run my app, however, I get this error:

```
errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/invalid-credential',
    message: 'Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app'
```

Node.js code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")

admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),})



const registrationToken = 'ePdAwFHd_EBJufZC6XQU8l:APA91bEYD5pFKIMuPwO7oAlKWqbENUXXG_TsLf67IS1Lyf-ge9szJ5Eqo0W8GTqgyheXSyNrNY6_QbU5V8nq39hj42cgphRG9PClgKOY8Ugc6aOFMTTY9t5pWrV_suzvzEXH2cprm3Nv';

const message = {
    data: {
        score: '850',
        time: '2:45'
    },
    token: registrationToken
};


admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Success")
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error Sending Message", error)
    })
```

After following the docs provided in the comments, it seemed like I was on the right track. But now `gcloud` is throwing an error about my `.json`:

(gcloud.auth.application-default.login) Invalid file format. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets Expected a JSON object with a single property for a "web" or "installed" application

I downloaded the json from the specified source in the docs... what's going wrong now?

Comment: I see a comma ',' after `credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()` in admin.initializeApp. Was this intentional?  If you are not passing any parameters like projectId,databaseURL keep it only `admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()}) ` Or if you want to specify projectId and other parameters, follow this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#testing_with_gcloud_end_user_credentials)

Comment: I think the comma was in the docs code I was following. I noticed it as well. The link you provided looks like the right source. I'll check it out.

Comment: Ok, now gcloud is throwing an error with respect to my json...

Answer (score 1):

I think the docs I was reading was misleading. I can successfully authenticate a node application by simply downloading the private key from firebase, then using the following code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("/filepath/to/private/key");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```